# Access parent scope from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive and I am trying to access the parent scope.The SelectedItemChange doesnt fire up and I can not access the value of Test1.

```
app.directive('driverNotes', function ($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "../HtmlTemplates/notesTempl.html",
        controller: function ($scope, $http) {

            console.log($scope.$parent.Test1);

            $scope.SelectedItemChange = function(item) {
                if (item != undefined || item != null) {
                    console.log(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Directive template

```
<md-input-container class="notesTable" flex-gt-sm ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" ">
<table class="notesTable">
    <tr><th>Description</th><th>Date</th><th>Down</th><th>Premium</th><th>Date Updated</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="note in notesSearch">

    </tr>
</table>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: You should pass `test1` value to the directive through the directive scope property. How does the directive template looks like?

Comment: Thank you, I added the directive template above

Comment: where is `$scope.SelectedItemChange ` in directive template?

Comment: I don't see `SelectedItemChange` being called in your template, this would explain why it's not fired...

Comment: SelectedItemChange is fired in the parent template. How can I access it? I added above the parent template as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `scope: true`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("parentCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'daddy';
});

app.directive('child', function ($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'I am a child of {{parentName}}',
        scope: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.parentName = $scope.$parent.name;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="parentCtrl as vm">
    <child></child>
  </div>
</div>
```